# CommandTimeout for DbContext

Tags: c#, .net-7.0, ef-core-7.0

I register `DbContext` using *Dependency Injection*, where I use connection string and `CommandTimeout(600)` option.

But when I use the `sqlServerOption` having command timeout set, it is not working. In resolved context I always receive timeout used in connection string (or default if not specified in connection string).
I don't want to set timeout via connection string for some reasons. What's wrong there please? I found question [How to set CommandTimeout for DbContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549640/how-to-set-commandtimeout-for-dbcontext), but solved differently.

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(
    options => options.UseSqlServer(
        "someConnectionString",
        sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(600))); //600s
```

Answer (score 0):

did you pass options parameters to DbContext base?

```
 public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {       
        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDBContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        ....
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I have it as you write.